# Java - jframe does not fit set dimensions

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've used methods in `JFrame`:

```
setSize(600, 600);
setResizable(true);
```

Next I've created a `JButton`, and set it's bounds to `0,0,600,600`.
I've found that the button is a bit (~40) bigger than the window. It made me some problems when I tried to put a few components exactly where I wanted to. I am using null layout. How to fix it and make my frame exactly `600x600`?

Comment: `"I am using null layout."` -- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms different from the original one. Follow @Robin's suggestions as they are right on the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is to get rid of the `null` layout and use a `LayoutManager` instead. If you want a component to take all available space, use a `BorderLayout` and put the component in the `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

To answer your specific question: the size of the `JFrame` is 600 by 600, but that is not the size of its content pane. The `JFrame` also contains window decorations which take up some of the size.

You could try to remove those decorations, or simply make your `JFrame` bigger. Or start wondering about your requirement to have a `JFrame` with a content pane of exactly 600 by 600 while it is still resizable by the user.

Comment: But how can I remove the top bar etc to make pane exactly as i want? The frame was resizable only to check if the button is bigger

Comment: Have you tried checking the javadoc ? My answer contains all the keyworks you need

Comment: Also `setResizable` can change the frame decorations, making the content size different based on the it is or isn't resizable...